# number of samples needed to determine quantile

Tags: probability, estimation

I am trying to estimate 16th, 50th, and 84th percentiles of some quantity $b$, and it would be helpful to know if I have enough samples to do so reliably (say, at the 1% level). Sound like a beginner question? Perhaps it is, but maybe I'm not thinking of it correctly.

I have data in many ($\ell \sim 4000$) dimensions, which I am projecting down to just a few ($q \sim 6$) dimensions to ease computation and to take advantage of covariance in the data (i.e., using a principal components basis set). I project the data onto those principal components, subject to observational noise, and get an estimate of principal component amplitudes $A$ and their covariance $\Sigma_A$.

In order to determine the value of some property $b$ of the object I have observed, I have to compare the data to models (for which I know the value of $b$). I am doing this by taking the likelihood of each model $\mathcal{L}_\text{model} \sim (A_\text{model} - A)^T \Sigma_A^{-1} (A_\text{model} - A)$ and using it as a weight on the associated $b_\text{model}$. I then find the percentiles using that weighted distribution.

I want to be able to flag when my estimates of percentile values of $b$ are unreliable. In the past, I have required that some number $n \sim 10$ models must have a likelihood at least $f \sim 0.1$ times as big as the model with the largest likelihood, but this has not been a reliable heuristic.

I have seen resources [like this](https://wiki.analytica.com/index.php?title=Selecting_the_Sample_Size) devoted to choosing sample size, but it seems my problem is distinct in that I have models that I am weighting rather than a population I am sampling from: I specifically need models *nearby* to $A$ in the $\Sigma_A^{-1}$ sense. Is there a condition that I can use that prescribes (for instance) a minimum number of models within some $\Delta \log \mathcal{L}$ of $A$ which will tell me when my percentiles aren't good to about $1\%$?

Comment: You're not using the word "sample" correctly. The question should be whether you have a big enough sample. What you are calling samples are observations in a sample.

Comment: quantity b, dimension, property b are the same thing -random variable?

Comment: @user158565, "property" b and "quantity" b are the same -- just some random variable pertaining to the object that I'm observing that I want to estimate